# Alguien sabe porque me tira este error y como puedo solucionarlo?

Tags: php, mysql

Recoverable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string in C:\xampp\htdocs\BaseDeDatos\busqueda.php on line 14
Este es el codigo:

```
if (isset($_POST['boton'])) {
     $contraN=$_POST['ConN'];
     $contraN2=$_POST['ConN2'];
     $contraV=$_POST['ConV'];
     require 'conexion.php';

     if (!empty($contraN) && !empty($contraN2) && !empty($contraV)) {
        $buscarPass="SELECT Contraseña from usuario where Contraseña='".$contraV."'";
        $consultaPass=mysqli_query($conexion,$buscarPass);

        if ($consultaPass) {
            echo $consultaPass;
        }else {
            echo "Contraseña incorrecta";
        }
```

Este es el conexion.php:

```
<?php 
$host="localhost";
$usuario="web";
$clave="hola1234";
$bd="web";

$conexion= mysqli_connect($host,$usuario,$clave,$bd);



?>
```

Comment: Te falta hacer *fetch*.

Comment: que es fetch y para que sirve?

Comment: @Lukas4 puedes publicar tu `conexion.php`  (en caso de de que tengas credenciales de una db publica cambialas por seguridad)

Comment: Ya esta publicado el conexion.php

Answer (score 1):

Estás retornando un arreglo por lo cual te hace falta el fetch, al realizar un echo te da error por que no puedes realizar un echo a un arreglo por lo cual debes retornar el fetch o fetch_all asignado a la variable y donde quieras recurrir, obtienes la $variable[0]

Answer (score 1):

he agregado el fetch de la consulta, he comentado cada detalle de lo que he hecho en el código,

```
if (isset($_POST['boton'])) {
    $contraN=$_POST['ConN'];
    $contraN2=$_POST['ConN2'];
    $contraV=$_POST['ConV'];
    require 'conexion.php';

        if (!empty($contraN) && !empty($contraN2) && !empty($contraV)) {
            $buscarPass="SELECT Contraseña from usuario where Contraseña='".$contraV."'";
            $consultaPass=mysqli_query($conexion,$buscarPass);
        
        //EXTRAER LA CONTRASEÑA DE LA CONSULTA
        $password = "";
        //Recorre cada fila que retorna la consulta
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($consultaPass)){
            $password = $row["Contraseña"];
        }
        //Validamos que la pasword no esté vacía
        if ($password != "") {
            echo $password;
        }else {
            echo "Contraseña incorrecta";
        }
    
    ...
```

Ten en cuenta que muchos usuarios pueden tener la misma contraseña. Puedes agregar al usuario en el `WHERE` de la query para que siempre retorne 1 row